# Scrolling Website to 3rd page

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am making a scrolling website and in my header i want to put the links to my second and third page .

```
$(".main").moveTo(3);
```

This is the function but how do it put it into a button or a text ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function scrollTo(id) { 
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(id).offset().top - 50}, 1000);}

<a href="javascript:scrollTo('#link1');">link1</a>
<a href="javascript:scrollTo('#link2');">link2</a>

<div id="link1"></div>
<div id="link2"></div>
```

:) this is my solution.

If it doesn't fit your site, you should edit your offset to whatever fits.

Comment: the function should be in the header ?

Comment: i will recommend the bottom.

Comment: you have to make the class to an ID for it to work.
the .page1 should be #page1

Comment: i didn't understand what you mean by that . Can you edit it in the link ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.your-button-class').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".main").moveTo(3);
});
```

.your-button-class is the link you would want to click on so you can change that to whatever you want. I added preventDefault so the page wouldn't jump.